# RoleDefinitionBindings (401) after creating ShareLink

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, 2016, 401, role-assignment

I am a Site admin an the SC (so I have FullControl / EnumeratePermissions).
For my application I use this API call on every Item with UniquePermissions:

```
${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('${List}')/items(${ItemID})/roleassignments?$expand=Member/users,RoleDefinitionBindings
```

without any problems (because I have FullControl).

**The Problem**

After I create a sharing link to a file I suddenly get a 401 for the mentioned API call on that file with an existing ShareLink. When I delete the ShareLink everything works as intended again.

I already searched for any changes on my permissions for that item by using this API Call before and after creating the ShareLink:

```
${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('${List}')/items(${ItemID})/effectiveBasePermissions
```

There are no differences seen on my PermissionKind.

My guess is that by creating this ShareLink and afterward asking for the roleassignments again I'm trying to access the SC Owners rights? And that's prohibited as I don't have the FullMask permission?

Thank you!